# How to invert a contextual filter which is a taxonomy term ID?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that displays a number of nodes according to a taxonomy. I do this by adding a `Contextual Filter -> Has Term ID` and to get this value from the URL to filter out all nodes related to that taxonomy.

What I need to show in a view is precisely the opposite. I need to show all nodes **except** the nodes filtered out by the contextual filter of term ID. In a way, I need to show all content **NOT** tagged with the taxonomy term in the URL.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this, but at the bottom of the contextual filter form, under 'More" is a button that reads:
Exclude
If selected, the numbers entered for the filter will be excluded rather than limiting the view.

Have you tried this?  Please follow up with a comment for your results.

Comment: I tested this on a nid contextual filter. It worked.